# accessing an element in the array using json

Tags: javascript, php, json

i have the following php code:

```
<?php
$library =
    '{
        "closets":[
                    {"id":"001","theme":"literature","shelves":
                    {
                        "books":[
                            {"id":"b1","genre":"english Literature"},
                            {"id":"b2","genre":"arabic literature"},
                            {"id":"b3","genre":"french literature"}  
                        ]
                    }
                    },
                    {"id":"002","theme":"comedy","shelves":{
                            "books":[
                                {"id":"b11","genre":"english comedy"},
                                {"id":"b22","genre":"arabic comedy"},
                                {"id":"b33","genre":"french comedy"}  
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {"id":"003","theme":"history","shelves":{
                            "books":[
                                {"id":"b11","genre":"english history"},
                                {"id":"b22","genre":"arabic history"},
                                {"id":"b33","genre":"french history"}  
                            ]
                        }
                    }
        ]
    }';

$literature = $_POST["literature"];
$comedy     = $_POST["comedy"];
$history    = $_POST["history"];

$literatureBooks = library.closets.shelves.books;
$comedyBooks     = library.closets.shelves.books;
$historyBooks    = library.closets.shelves.books;

if ($literature) {
    echo $literatureBooks;
} elseif ($comedy) {
    echo $comedyBooks;
} elseif ($history) {
    echo $historyBooks;
}
?>
```

and the following javascript:
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#literature").click(function(){

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post';
    url:'library.php';
    data:'literature';
    dataType:'json';
    success: function(data)
    {
        for (var i in data){
            $("#books").append('literature Books are'+data[i]+<'br/'>);
        }
    }


});
}); 
$("#comedy").click(function(){

$.ajax({
    type:'post';
    url:'library.php';
    data:'comedy';
    dataType:'json';
    success: function(data)
    {
        for (var i in data){
            $("#books").append('comedy Books are'+data[i]+<'br/'>);
        }
    }


});
}); 
$("#history").click(function(){

$.ajax({
    type:'post';
    url:'library.php';
    data:'history';
    dataType:'json';
    success: function(data)
    {
        for (var i in data){
            $("#books").append('history Books are'+data[i]+<'br/'>);
        }
    }


});
}); 
});
```

the html code is a three buttons when u click one for example the literature button, all books ids should be printed (b1,b2,b3).i have written the code but i don't know how to access the element book in the array library.
 so my problem is with declaring these variales:

```
$literatureBooks=library.closets.shelves.books;
$comedyBooks=library.closets.shelves.books;
$historyBooks=library.closets.shelves.books;
```

Comment: plus that it seems i have quotation mistakes in the $library if you could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle your JSON with PHP, you have to transform it into a PHP data structure. After that, you can access whatever you need:

```
$library = json_decode($library, true);
$literatureBooks = $library['closets'][0]['shelves']['books'];
$comedyBooks     = $library['closets'][1]['shelves']['books'];
$historyBooks    = $library['closets'][2]['shelves']['books'];
```

Instead of an array, you could also transform $library into an object:

```
$library = json_decode($library);
$literatureBooks = $library->closets[0]->shelves->books;
$comedyBooks     = $library->closets[1]->shelves->books;
$historyBooks    = $library->closets[2]->shelves->books;
```

For the ajax calls use something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',        // <----- Use comas here, not semicolon
    url:'library.php',
    data:'closet=literature',
    // ...
```

Then in PHP you could skip the whole `if ($literature) {}` block and just echo the right closet:

```
$closet = $_POST['closet']; # You should sanitize this
echo $($closet . 'Books');
```

Comment: what about the data sent in the ajax frm is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that would work. But you could do it more elegant/flexible... see answer above.

Comment: im having an error in :
    $literature = $_POST["literature"];
    $comedy     = $_POST["comedy"];
    $history    = $_POST["history"];

Comment: See the modified answer above.

Comment: can you help me to parse the main object which is library and get from it another object only 'literature'

Comment: (add a new line after every ;)
`$library = json_decode($library);`
`$literature = $library->closets[0];`
`echo $literature->id;`
`print_r($literature->shelves);`

Comment: I would appreciate if you flag the answer as correct ;)